# ‎SpeechSynthesis and chrome while casting a tab to a chromecast

Tags: html, google-chrome, text-to-speech, chromecast

I tried browsing around finding information about this, but to my surprise I could not find anything. Blows my mind, but here we go: I have a HTML5 application which is running in chrome. It has background sounds and music. It also uses ‎SpeechSynthesis for some text-to-speech (TTS).

When I cast the browser over to the chromecast, I hear all the audio fine. Except, the TTS is playing on my computer. I thought this odd, as I figured all audio from Chrome should now be going to my TVs chromecast.

Has anyone encountered this?
Is it normal?
Is there a way around it?

If there is no way around it, is there anyway to detect when I am in casting mode from my application so I can shut TTS off. According to the HTML5 application, TTS is available...it just is not properly going through the chromecast.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be a chromcast bug. I can reproduce that behavior.

Comment: @astreal thank you for confirming. I will submit a bug to chromecast. I am glad it was not just me :)

Comment: this is still an issue? i cannot hear my TTS tab speaking on the casted device

Comment: As far as I know @Miguel, it is still an issue. The official response I got from google was it is working as intended and they have no plans on fixing it.